# React gives me TypeError: props.posts.map is not a function when trying to map through an array of posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've been trying to write some simple React code to fetch data from a mock API and display it on a page. But when trying to map through my array of posts returned by axios from an async function it gives me an error.

I've tried setting props.posts to a variable and it still doesn't work.

Here's my app structure and the function I use to get the users from the API as JSON:

```
function App() {
    // Hook that declares a posts state
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getPosts().then(setPosts)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <header className='App-header'>
                <PostList posts={posts} />
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

function PostList(props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.posts.map(post => (
                <Post post={post} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

function Post(props) {
    return <li>{props.post.title}</li>
}

async function getPosts() {
    try {
        let posts = await axios.get(
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        )
        console.log(posts)
        return posts
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

And this is the problematic bit:

```js
function PostList(props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.posts.map(post => (
                <Post post={post} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

I expect the application to map through the array of posts but it gives me an error every time.

Comment: Have you tried loging posts prop in PostList? What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios return an object with info about the request (status, headers, data, etc) I think you need to find request.data. The error is because you are trying to map over an object instead of an array.

```
 async function getPosts() {
    try {
        let posts = await axios.get(
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        )
        return posts.data 
               ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ
    } catch (error) {
       ...
    }
}
```

docs: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: That's the correct answer. I refactored my getPosts to this: 
`async function getPosts() {
 try {
  let response = await axios.get(
   'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  )
  let posts = response.data
  console.log(posts)
  return posts
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
 }
}
`
and it worked instantly. Thank you! I'll be more careful about reading the docs next time.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that your axios request is failing for some reason. Maybe there's an error, or a CORS problem, and `posts` isn't an array when you go to set it. You should have some validation either in your `useEffect` or in `getPosts()` like:

```
async function getPosts() {
    try {
        let posts = await axios.get(
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        )
        if (!Array.isArray(posts)) {
          console.log("posts isn't an array: ", posts);
          return [];
        }
        return posts;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred: ', error);
        return [];
    }
}
```

Just make sure, even if there's an error, you're always returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ternary for the posts attribute in case post is not an array:

```
return (
    <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
            <PostList posts={posts && posts.length > 0 ? posts : []} />
        </header>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: You can also use defaultProps for this kind of thing, makes the component code a little cleaner IMO